# Merge pdf pages of different size to e.g. DIN A0

Tags: pdf, merge

Given e.g. 10 PDF files with different page sizes, most of them could be combined to a single DIN A0 page. I need to arrange them on as less DIN A0 pages as possible before printing. Is there any software that can do this automatically or at least provide a nice GUI for arranging pages of different size on a new page format (DIN A0)?

Answer (score 0):

the vector software Inkscape is free and avalible for most os's . will do that as long as the pdf's are single page import one at a time. Scribus may do it also